# Dynamic Programming - With 3 sequences.and finding the maximized value

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

[Question I need Help with: CHECK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o5I1.png)

Need some help with this problem.

The solution that I came up with so far is:

Treat B as an input and go backwards, so take last value of B and Look through A from the back to find the something that matches B. Then take the First value of B and look through A from the front and find the first Value that matches. Save both of these values.

Then do comparisons between the 2 upper and lower limits to find any values greater than the ones found in out first step. so that it fulfills the requirements. SO in the example given in the question of B = (x,y) X has to come before Y, so even if there is X which is the largest but comes after the last Y, we can not choose that.

I believe that it would run in O(MxN) time but I am very unsure and thats why I am asking you guys.

Thanks for your time and hopefully you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution doesn't sound at all like dynamic programming.

The problem basically asks to find a maximum sum [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), where the common subsequence is between `A` and `B` and the sum is from `P`.

It should be possible to adapt the LCS solution for your problem. Since you must pick sums from `P`, consider the classic backtracking algorithm to get the actual LCS once the `LCS` matrix is built:

```
backtrack(LCS, A, B, i, j):
    if i == 0 or j == 0
        return ""

    if A[i] == B[j]:
        return backtrack(LCS, A, B, i-1, j-1) + A[i]
    else if LCS[i-1, j] > LCS[i, j-1]:
        return backtrack(LCS, A, B, i-1, j)
    return backtrack(LCS, A, B, i, j-1)
```

Now you need to find the maximum sum:

```
backtrack(LCS, A, B, i, j, s=0):
    if i == 0 or j == 0
        return s

    if A[i] == B[j]:
        return backtrack(LCS, A, B, i-1, j-1, s + P[i])
    else if LCS[i-1, j] > LCS[i, j-1]:
        return backtrack(LCS, A, B, i-1, j, s)
    else if LCS[i-1, j] < LCS[i, j-1]:
        return backtrack(LCS, A, B, i, j-1, s)
    else:
        return max(backtrack(LCS, A, B, i-1, j, s),
                   backtrack(LCS, A, B, i, j-1, s))
```

You might have to apply memoization for an efficient implementation. It should also be possible to compute a sum matrix alongside (or even instead of) the LCS matrix.